# rename file in g drive based on folder and subfodler name

Tags: google-sheets, directory, rename

I am looking for google scripts (with google sheet) that will help with bulk file renaming based on the folder name and subfolder name they are under.
Structure is
Container Folder contains Folder and Subfolder and file1, file2, file3
Example (Container Folder is the folder we will assign to script to look in this folder id)
Bird(Folder) contains Parrot (Subfolder) and in this subfolder there are bmdscxf.jpg (first order), hhhhh.jpg (second order), ssmnt.jpg (third order).
So after rename the files should be 
bmdscxf.jpg will be renamed to Bird-Parrot-01.jpg,
hhhhh.jpg will be renamed to Bird-Parrot-02.jpg,
ssmnt.jpg will be renamed to Bird-Parrot-03.jpg. 
There could be up to 10 or more files in each subfolder and multi subfolders in each folder, and multi folders in a folder container to loop through.
 What would be the best way to do this? 
Thank you!